# How Do I Send a Message to a Privately Linked Group in Telegram with Python?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync
client.start()
destination_group_invite_link=grouplink #t.me/xxxxxxx
entity=client.get_entity(destination_group_invite_link)
client.send_file(entity=entity, message="xxxx")
```

With this code I can send message to public linked group. But how do I send a message to a group with a private link?

#t.me/+xxxxxxxxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved the Problem.

Just specify the id of the group as the target. And it works :) Thanks for the @kekkoilmedikit help

Comment: Would you please post your full code, that solved the problem? Thank you :)

Comment: Just enter the id of the group instead of the entity.
entity="-123456"

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But how do I get the id? All I have is the invitation link of the form: t.me/+xxx. And client.get_entity('+xxx') gives an error.

Comment: In modified telegram apps. For example, it appears right next to the group in the kotatogram. https://www.hizliresim.com/62kd3up

Answer (score 0):

first, you need to join the group, to do so:

```
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import ImportChatInviteRequest
                                                ^
                                                |      
                                    (this will throw an error you are already in the group)
```

if you are already inside of the group:

```
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import CheckChatInviteRequest
```

code with ImportChatInviteRequest:

```
 update = await client(ImportChatInviteRequest("Group link"))
            group_to_search = (update.chats.Chat.id)
```

code with CheckChatInviteRequest: [for this you need the group link, specifically the hash, to find it you need to to replace "https://t.me/+" with a blank space]

```
group_to_search = await client(CheckChatInviteRequest(hash = link_to_search))
            group_to_search = str(group_to_search.chat.id)
```

Comment: I am in the group. I just want to send the message I want to the group. How can I do. How will I determine the message I will send to the codes you have written?

Comment: await client.send_message(entity = group_to_search, message = "message")

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70825643/17575870

Comment: you can search an entity (a group, a chat, a channel ecc...) by a few methods:
1) entity name
2) entity id
3) entity hash
4) entity link

Comment: I can already send messages to public groups with Telethon. But I can't send messages to groups whose addresses are hidden.

For example: I can send a message to t.me/KekikKahve.

But: I can't send a message to the group on the t.me/+XsadDdfd link.

Comment: Calm down mate :) I was just wondering how I can send a message to the group in a private link. Thank you for your help.

Comment: you can send a message in a private group only if you are inside it, 
so with various methods you che get the group id, displayed name ecc...
by theese 2 things you can send a message to the group.

if you want to send the message via the link you need to resolve it first and get the hash.

Comment: I am in the group. But I can't send messages. Is it enough to get the name of the group I'm in? For example Group name is "Pubg Mobile Group XX"

Comment: yeah, that's the third time i say that you can use  the group name to send mesasge

Comment: Ok, my english is very bad. You're right. Last few questions. What should be the target to send a message to the group I am in with its name?

For example: destination_group_invite_link

Comment: await client.send_message(entity= "Pubg Mobile Group XX", message = "message")

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. Thanks for all your help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70826554/17575870